# mkdir command not found (gitlab)

Tags: shell, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm getting the following error in my code.
/bin/bash: line 126: -mkdir: command not found

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

build the car:
    stage: build
    script:
        -mkdir build 
        -cd build
        -touch car.txt
        -echo "chassis" > car.txt
        -echo "engine" > car.txt
        -echo "wheels" > car.txt
```

Comment: It's `-<space>mkdir`, like `- mkdir`, not `-mkdir`

Comment: Same with all of the other commands. You need a space after each dash for this to be a valid list of commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need whitespace after the `-` for an array. Otherwise, the YAML syntax assumes these are all a single string, not parts of an array.

So what you should have:

```yaml
    script:
        - mkdir build 
        - cd build
        - touch car.txt
        # ... etc
```

This becomes a bit more obvious if you convert your YAML into a structured object format.

What you have:

```
{'build the car': {'stage': 'build',
  'script': '-mkdir build -cd build -touch car.txt -echo "chassis" > car.txt -echo "engine" > car.txt -echo "wheels" > car.txt'}}
```

Versus when you use the correct format that creates an array:

```
{'build the car': {'stage': 'build',
  'script': ['mkdir build',
   'cd build',
   'touch car.txt',
   'echo "chassis" > car.txt',
   'echo "engine" > car.txt',
   'echo "wheels" > car.txt']}}
```